# rails form using form_for not submitting using post method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a comments resource nested in courses resource:
routes.rb:

```
    ..
    resources :courses do
      resources :comments, :only => [:new, :create]
    end
    ..
```

I want to show the form to give comment in the show page of any course.
comments_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user
  before_action :set_course, only: [:new]

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment Posted"
      redirect_to course_path(@comment.course)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Comment can't posted"
      redirect_to course_path(@comment.course)
    end
  end

  private

    def set_course
      @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    end

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body ,:rating, :course_id, :user_id)
    end

end
```

I  have put @comment = Comment.new in show action of my courses controller.

The form i am using in view is:
          
          <%= form_for([@course, @comment], method: "post", :url => course_comments_path(@course, @comment) ) do |f| %>

```
          <div class="rrating" style="width:140px;">
            <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 1) %>
            <%= f.label(:rating_1, "1") %>
            <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 2) %>
            <%= f.label(:rating_2, "2") %>
            <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 3) %>
            <%= f.label(:rating_3, "3") %>
            <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 4) %>
            <%= f.label(:rating_4, "4") %>
            <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 5) %>
            <%= f.label(:rating_5, "5") %>
          </div>

            <%= f.text_field :body, :class => "form-control", id: "exampleInputEmail1", placeholder: "Add a comment" %>

                    </fieldset>
      <%= f.submit("Post", class: 'btn btn-success') %>
      <% end %>
      </form>
```

When i click on submit, a get request gets sent to the same page i am in currently(with all params in url).
I tried putting the form in a seperate new page for comments, it still dosen't work.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try form_for like this, `<%= form_for([@course, @comment],:url => course_comments_path(@course, @comment),method: "post" ) do |f| %>` Put Url as second argument

Comment: anyone has any solution...i still can't get this to work...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got the problem  and thought i should put it up for other's future reference.
The problem was that form_for was enclosed in form tags.

Answer (score 0):

This might work, show page :

```
<%= form_for([@course, @course.comments.build] , method: :post) do |f| %>
            <fieldset class="form-group" style="margin-top:0px; !important">

                      <div class="rrating" style="width:140px;">
                        <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 1) %>
                        <%= f.label(:rating_1, "1") %>
                        <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 2) %>
                        <%= f.label(:rating_2, "2") %>
                        <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 3) %>
                        <%= f.label(:rating_3, "3") %>
                        <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 4) %>
                        <%= f.label(:rating_4, "4") %>
                        <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 5) %>
                        <%= f.label(:rating_5, "5") %>
                      </div>

                        <%= f.text_field :body, :class => "form-control", id: "exampleInputEmail1", placeholder: "Add a comment" %>

                                </fieldset>
                  <%= f.submit("Post", class: 'btn btn-success') %>
    <% end %>
```

comments controller :

```
 def create
            @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
            @comment = @course.comments.create(comment_params)
            @comment.user = current_user

    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment Posted"
      redirect_to course_path(@comment.course)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Comment can't posted"
      redirect_to course_path(@comment.course)
    end
  end
```

Comment: this dosen't work...it still gives a get request...plus you have a syntax errr, missing closing ')'...

Comment: updated the answer , fixing syntax error and method: :post added to form

Comment: put method: :post inside the form_for () bracket

Answer (score -1):

Since you are assigning a `course` to the `comment` in the `create action` manually, You can send the `@comment` object only to comment form and you can go to create action.

Send the `course_id` through a hidden field from the form to create action

```html
<%= form_for @comment, url: course_comments_path do |f| %>
  <fieldset class="form-group" style="margin-top:0px; !important">
    <div class="rrating" style="width:140px;">
      <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 1) %>
      <%= f.label(:rating_1, "1") %>
      <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 2) %>
      <%= f.label(:rating_2, "2") %>
      <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 3) %>
      <%= f.label(:rating_3, "3") %>
      <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 4) %>
      <%= f.label(:rating_4, "4") %>
      <%= f.radio_button(:rating, 5) %>
      <%= f.label(:rating_5, "5") %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :course_id, value: @course.id %
    </div>
    <%= f.text_field :body, :class => "form-control", id: "exampleInputEmail1", placeholder: "Add a comment" %>
  </fieldset>
  <%= f.submit("Post", class: 'btn btn-success') %>
<% end %>
```

Now you will get `course_id` through the params and assign that course to the comment.

Comment: Sorry but what are you talking about? It's an option hash, the order doesn't matter...

Comment: @2called-chaos, I am sorry but, as every where I see the url is in second argument and I always take the same way, so I asked him to try if it works.I changed my answer.